# Google App Script function to get rownumber given text

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I am using google spreadsheets and Apps Script.

I wanted to know if there is a way in Apps Script to get the rownumber for a value in cell.

Assumption is each row has unique value in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function like this :

```
function findRow(val) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var n=0 ; n<data.length ; n++){
    if(data[n].indexOf(val)>-1){n++ ; return n };// if found return row number
  }
  return -1;//else return -1 = not found.
}
```

usage :

let's say you are looking for the row number of a cell containing "hello", just use

```
var row = findRow("hello");
```

You can also use it as a custom function directly in you sheet, in this case simply type 
`=findRow("hello")` in a cell and this cell will show the row number of the one that contains "hello"

Comment: why is this downvoted without any comment ? anything wrong with it ?